# Laravel 5 Controller using variable arguments

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a controller in Laravel 5.

I would like to write a controller function that accepts variable arguments.

For example,

```
public function show(Request $request, ...$id)
{
    // handle multiple $id values here
}
```

The reason is that I have a url structure that has 'nested' models.
For instance:

```
\item\{$id}
\parent\{$parent_id}\item\{$id}
\grandparent\{$grandparent_id}\parent\{$parent_id}\item\{$id}
```

The routes are defined as:

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
Route::resource('parent.item', 'ParentController');
Route::resource('grandparent.parent.item', 'GrandparentController');
```

My desire is to write a single show() method as a trait that each controller can use.

Because of the structure of my database, it is possible.
But the UrlGenerator keeps throwing a UrlGenerationException when I try to use variable arguments.  It seems like it doesn't understand this construct?

Comment: And what does your corresponding routes definition/s look like?

Comment: @Jonathan, I've added the routes information you requested

Comment: Have you solved this yet? Your explanation is a bit confusing. You have different controllers set up with those different routes, so requests aren't uniformly received. The scope of what you're asking for isn't clear to me yet. You stated a desire for a single `show()` method, but allude to at least 3 separate controllers. Can you give some more explanation around  what you're trying to achieve and what the constraints are, e.g. you whether *must* use separate controllers, etc. Are you duplicating code in each controller's `show()` or redirect the input to another class, or what, exactly?

Comment: @Jonathan my hope was that the UrlGenerator was able to pass route parameters as a single variable argument.  Then I can have a single function signature, rather than having to have a signature for each of the numbers of parameters

Comment: If I were in your situation I would pass the entire request to a custom controller, and do your logic there. Or use the resource routes except for your show, and siphon off those routes as separate ones into the aforementioned custom (centralised) controller method. But without really fully understanding what you're doing, not much in the mood for writing up anything yet

Comment: @Jonathan what you mentioned is basically what I'm doing. But I don't know how to get the route parameters as an array.  Each of the controllers in my example are derived from a common controller, and show is implemented with a common trait (that's the hope anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's an idea for you that should get you on the right path:
For the various resource routes you defined, re-declare them to exclude the 'show' action, and define a separate GET route to map the routes you are trying to centralise.

`app/Http/routes.php`:

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController', ['except' => ['show']]);
Route::get('item/{item}', ['uses' => 'AggregateController@handleShow', 'as' => 'item.show']);

Route::resource('parent.item', 'ParentController', ['except' => ['show']]);
Route::get('parent/{parent}/item/{item}', ['uses' => 'AggregateController@handleShow', 'as' => 'parent.item.show']);

Route::resource('grandparent.parent.item', 'GrandParentController', ['except' => ['show']]);
Route::get('grandparent/{grandparent}/parent/{parent}/item/{item}', ['uses' => 'AggregateController@handleShow', 'as' => 'grandparent.parent.item.show']);
```

`app/Http/Controllers/AggregateController.php`:

```
class AggregateController extends Controller
{
    public function handleShow(Request $request, ...$items)
    {
        dd($request->path(), $items);
    }
}
```

`http://stackoverflow42005960.dev/grandparent/1/parent/2/item/3`:

```
"grandparent/1/parent/2/item/3"
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]
```

If you still have issues with getting the variable arguments, then check your PHP version and if `< 5.6` you'll have to use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: thank you for your reply, it really helped me!  Interestingly enough, I was able to still use the Route::resource syntax for defining items.  I don't know why it didn't work when I tried the first time.  However I am now getting the route parameters in the variable arguments array.

Comment: You're welcome :) but how on earth are you able to get the arguments to the right controller method if you haven't overriden the resource? I guess you don't need to if you want to write the logic in each controller show method, but, that defeats the point of not repeating yourself? What did you do in the end?

Comment: I implemented show as a trait.  I'll try to post a stripped down example tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to go about this. For example, you can use a comma separated list in routes and simply explode in controller.

The way you have it currently, you will have to use a fixed number of optional parameters, e.g.

```
public function show(Request $request, $id1, $id2 = false, $id3 = false)
{
    //if parent item exists
    if($id2)
    {
        //if grandparent item resource
        if($id3)
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //just item
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for confirming, I was thinking that might be the case